# Beautiful soup - data not in HTML file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python. I am trying to scrape data from a website and the data I want can not be seen on view > source in the browser. It comes from another file. It is possible to scrape the actual data on the screen with Beautifulsoup and Python?

example site www[dot]catleylakeman[dot]co(dot)uk/cds_banks.php

If not, is this possible using another route?

Thanks

Comment: .. No, BeautifulSoup is for scraping HTML, not screens; it couldn't help at all with screen-scraping. You'd be better off using it to find the url of this 'other file' so you can scrape __that__.

Comment: well, the data seems to be generated by [this page](http://www.catleylakeman.co.uk/bankCDS.php), so why don't you use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "other file" is http://www.catleylakeman.co.uk/bankCDS.php?ignoreMe=1369145707664 - you can find this out (and I suspect you already have) by using chrome's developer tools, network tab (or the equivalent in your browser).

This format is easier to parse than the final html would be; generally HTML scrapers should be used as a last resort if the website does not publish raw data like the above.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, the url you are actually looking for is:

```
http://www.catleylakeman.co.uk/bankCDS.php?ignoreMe=1369146012122
```

I found it using the developer toolbar and looking at the network traffic (builtin to chrome and firefox, also using firebug). It gets called in with Ajax. You do not even need beatiful soup to parse that one as it seems to be a long string separated with `*|` and sometimes `**|`. The following should get you initial access to that data:

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.catleylakeman.co.uk/bankCDS.php?ignoreMe=1369146012122')
try:
    data = f.read().split('*|')
finally:
    f.close()
print data
```